# How to identify and delete or update duplicate rows in Mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql

Due to a recent bug, we have a table with multiple duplicate entries.
What I want to do is to find and ideally delete (or perhaps just update) the duplicate rows.

```
PersonGroup
-----------
id
personId
groupId
type
primary
value

select count(*) cnt from personGroup pg where type="FOO" group by personId having cnt > 1;
```

yields nearly 20k rows.  There should be 0.  Each `personId` should have only one entry for any given `type`.

I can write a program to fix this scenario but before I do that I'm wondering if there is a purely SQL solution.

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311903/remove-duplicate-rows-in-mysql

Comment: This is absolutely NOT a duplicate of that other stack question...that question should be titled "AVOID duplicate rows in Mysql"  This is a question about how to remove them once we have them.

Comment: @Nick please read this question and the other referenced question closer, this is not a duplicate.  The accepted answer in the other stack refers to setting an unique index which won't help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this query. I think it is pretty simple and yet effective:

```
delete from persongroup
 where id not in (
    select max(id)
      from persongroup
     group by PersonId);
```

if your table is too big then you can consider to write this with inner join

```
 delete persongroup
   from persongroup
  inner join (
     select max(id) as lastId, personId
       from personGroup
      group by personId
     having count(*) > 1) dup on dup.personId = persongroup.personId
  where persongroup.id < dup.lastId;
```

above query is not tested

Comment: Thank you.  I can test this for sure...I want to keep the most recent entry so reading through this I think that's what this will do...I'll test.

Comment: yes exactly, it keeps most recent record by id

Comment: This worked exactly as I needed it to...I had to add a group by `type` but that's because my original question didn't state that requirement.  Thank you!